# (Oracle)Getting max value across columns

Tags: sql, oracle

My goal is to get max value for each row.
For instance, my table has two columns, and the desired output is, 80,70 and 90 for each row.

I tried this code "SELECT MAX(column1, column2) from my_table" , and it showed error such as ORA-00909:invalid number of argumants

[my_table  and the desired output]

[image: my_table]

Comment: In the future, please post sample data as text that we can copy and paste not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `greatest` not `max`

```
   with x as (
      select 80 col1, 60 col2 from dual union all
      select 70, 50 from dual union all
      select 80, 90 from dual
    )
    select greatest( col1, col2 )
      from x
```